# How to properly test jQuery .slideToggle() via Qunit

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, qunit

I'm figuring out how to get a working Qunit test to verify that .slideToggle() acting on a element shades it up/down. I've made a very basic Qunit test fixture as shown here. The first problem is that the test 'shade, not visible' fails. The second problem is, it looks horrible to have the QUnit.test sitting inside the done() {} function call.
I've tried several incorrect strategies, including testing for is( ':visible'), .css('height'), I thought I had it by testing for display:none, so I'm at a loss on how to get this test to pass.

I have prepared a JSFiddle showing the problem test which I think should pass.
https://jsfiddle.net/chrismcginlay/tjLeqj01/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>                                                                              
<html>                                                                                       
<head>                                                                                       
    <meta charset="utf-8">                                                                   
    <title>Shading tests</title>                                                             
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="qunit.css">                                                 
</head>                                                                                      

<body>                                                                                       
    <div id="qunit"></div>                                                                   
    <div id="qunit-fixture">                                                                 
        <div id="shade">                                                                     
            <p>Some text to test</p>                                                         
        </div>                                                                               
    </div>                                                                                   
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>                      
    <script src="qunit.js"></script>                                                         
    <script>                                                                                 

QUnit.module("Shading Tests");                                                               
QUnit.test("shade, visible", function( assert ) {                                            
    assert.ok( $( '#shade' ).length, "div exists" );                                         
    assert.ok( $( '#shade' ).css( 'height' ) > '0px', "div has height" );                    
    assert.notEqual( $( '#shade' ).css( 'display' ), 'none', "div displayed");               
});                                                                                          
$( '#shade' ).slideToggle( "3000" );                                                         
$( '#shade' ).promise().done( function() {                                                   
    alert( 'Done with slideToggle');                                                         
    QUnit.test("shade, not visible", function( assert ) {                                    
        assert.ok( $( '#shade' ).length, "div exists" );                                     
        assert.equal(                                                                        
            $( '#shade' ).css( 'display' ), 'none', "div not displayed");                    
    });                                                                                      
});                                                                                          
    </script>                                                                                
</body>                                                                                      
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're testing that a jQuery function works? I mean jQuery tests their code, so you're testing that tested code works...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, my real code is testing that shade trigger elements properly activate and shade their respective target elements. I just prepared the above as simplest failure case when isolating exactly what it was that I couldn't figure to test properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution, thanks to shoky_ and robertmaxrees on IRC #jquery chat. As you can see, I had not properly deployed asynchronous testing. Updated the fiddle linked in my question to a working version.

```
QUnit.module("Shading Tests");
QUnit.test("shade, visible", function( assert ) {
  assert.ok( $( '#shade' ).length, "div exists" );
  assert.ok( $( '#shade' ).css( 'height' ) > '0px', "div has height" );
  assert.notEqual( $( '#shade' ).css( 'display' ), 'none', "div displayed");
});
QUnit.test("shade, not visible", function( assert ) {
    var done1 = assert.async();
    $( '#shade' ).slideToggle( 3000 );
    $( '#shade' ).promise().done( function() {
    assert.ok( $( '#shade' ).length, "div exists" );
    assert.equal( $( '#shade' ).css( 'display' ), 'none', "div not displayed");
  });
});
```